# SOAP with Attachment (SwA) in C#

Tags: c#, soap, mime, attachment

I need to use .NET in order to consume a JAVA written SOAP service which expects simple MIME attachments on some of its method.

Does anybody know how to accomplish it? I could not find any information about using WCF or even WSE clients with such attachments.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is [not supported by .NET clients](http://webservices20.blogspot.com/2008/10/web-service-attachments-support-matrix_11.html) natively. You might take a look at the following discussion on [MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/thread/145c2e7a-769d-4a40-b620-8cb7a22b8e7d). If you install [WSE 2.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=1ba1f631-c3e7-420a-bc1e-ef18bab66122&displaylang=en) there is an example at the following location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft WSE\v2.0\Samples\CS\QuickStart\Attachments\AttachmentsClient